# Why does the object of List<ArrayList<Integer>> misbehaving?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

PROBLEM: Given an integer array nums that may contain duplicates, print all possible subsets (the power set). The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. print the solution in any order.

CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 2, 2};
        ArrayList<Integer> subset = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> allSubsets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, len = nums.length;
        boolean flag;
        allSubsets.add(subset);
        System.out.println(allSubsets);
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for(j = i; j < len; j++) {
                flag = true;
                subset.clear();
                System.out.println(subset);
                System.out.println(allSubsets);
                for(k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                    subset.add(nums[k]);
                    
                }
                System.out.println(subset);
                System.out.println(allSubsets);
                for(List<Integer> temp: allSubsets) {
                    if(temp.equals(subset))
                        flag = false;
                }
                if(flag) {
                    allSubsets.add(subset);
                }
                System.out.println(allSubsets);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(allSubsets);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[]]

[]

[[]]

[1]

[[1]]

[[1]]

[]

[[]]

[1, 2]

[[1, 2]]

[[1, 2]]

[]

[[]]

[1, 2, 2]

[[1, 2, 2]]

[[1, 2, 2]]

[]

[[]]

[2]

[[2]]

[[2]]

[]

[[]]

[2, 2]

[[2, 2]]

[[2, 2]]

[]

[[]]

[2]

[[2]]

[[2]]

[[2]]
```

Why does the 'Allsubsets' change by itself after every iteration before evening adding an element to it.

PS: The extra SOP statements were just to check how is the programme executing itself.

Comment: You are clearing `subset` in every loop. Were you trying to create a new subset in every iteration?

Comment: The program continuously uses one and the same `ArrayList<Integer> subset`. Hence `temp.equals(subset)` will always evaluate to `true`. And since we add `subset` to `allSubsets`, when we change `subset`, it will also be changed in `allSubsets`. See [this Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/EXlZXO).

Comment: @aksappy Yes, that was my objective.

Comment: @Turing85, can you explain this behaviour demonstrated. I mean why does this happen?

Comment: Because we are working with references.